# RXJS Observable Epic LOCATION_CHANGE runs before protected route redirect

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, observable

I have the issue where I have a protected route that is picked up by the below Epic. If the criteria to access the protected route is not met, the user is redirected to another page. Unfortunately, the effect still runs which in this case is a promise that will fail and show an error to the user.

```
export const examplePageLoadEffect: Epic<AnyAction, IAppState> = (action$) =>
  action$
    .ofType(LOCATION_CHANGE)
    .map((action: LocationChangeAction) => action.payload.pathname)
    .filter((url) => /protected-path/.test(url))
    .switchMap((url) => {
        return Observable.fromPromise(fetchSomePromise())
          .switchMap((promiseResponse) => Observable.of(
            doSomethingWithPromise(promiseResponse)
          ))
          .catch((err) => Observable.of(doSomethingWithError(err));
      }
    );
```

Is there a way to get around this so that if the protected route is redirected to another route, this stops?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`takeUntil` operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/takeUntil) for that, see [Redux Observable - Cancellation](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/Cancellation.html)

Also, keep in mind that Promises usually not cancelable, so you may want to use Observables instead